# Can't download letsencrypt certificate using webroot method of certbot

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, lets-encrypt, iis-8.5, certbot

Following this [guide](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/windows-other) for windows installation, i try the webroot method, from an elevated cmd shell:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> certbot certonly --webroot
```

The command fails with unauthorized error, because IIS is does not expose hidden folder `.well-known` created by `certbot` tool.

I am running IIS 8.5 on a windows server.

How can i enable hidden folders in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the error returned by certbot says `type:unauthorized`, and the warning on the certbot guide about how hidden folder may be treated differently by IIS, the real problem is that IIS doesn't serve files with no extension, by default.

The path that letencrypt servers try to access is something like:

```
http://mydmain/.well-known/acme-challenge/<token>
```

where  as no file extension.

To IIS serve files with no extension, he needs to know what is the content type for those files. To do tell him, add the following mimemap setting to the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/xml" />
         </staticContent>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

To prevent exposure of unwanted content from your site, add a web.config file with that content to the `.well-know` folder

Try access some no extension file on that folder before run certbot again.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you!